# How can I add p-value from a correlation test and R² from a lm to a scatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have not been successful in adding both pvalue from a Kendall correlation and R² from a linear model. I am using `ggplot`.

I tried using `stat_fit_glance` and `stat_poly_eq` but that didn't work, it showed the following warning messages:

```
Warning messages:

1. Computation failed in `stat_poly_eq()`:
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable 

2. Computation failed in `stat_fit_glance()`:
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Then, I tried using `ggscatter` but then it couldn't find the `y` used.
I also tried adding it manually, but it didn't work because my `corr.test` is not a data frame.

This is the code that I have so far (it's only the scatter plot)

```
seq15 %>% ggplot(aes(Fe, Cr, color=depth)) +
  geom_point() + xlab(expression(paste("Fe mg"~ kg^-1~"2015"))) + 
  ylab(expression(paste("Cr mg"~ kg^-1))) +
  geom_smooth(data = subset(seq15, profundidade %in% c("0-3")), method = lm, se = FALSE, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("0-3 cm", "3-5 cm", "5-10 cm", "10-15 cm", "15-20 cm", "20-25 cm", "25-30 cm")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.1),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(color="black"), axis.line.x = element_line(color="black"),legend.title = element_text(color = "white"), legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

And the correlation test:

```
cor.test(seq15$Fe,seq15$Cr, method = "kendall")
```

Comment: Please share some sample data and show the code you tried that produced warnings. Otherwise this seems like a duplicate of [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/903061)

Comment: You want to add the values as text notes in the plot ??

Comment: yup @SantiagoI.Hurtado